# Wordpress Enqueue for homepage only, functions.php, wp-framework

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, homepage

I'd like to replace my:

```
    if(is_home())
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'homestuff', get_theme_part( THEME_JS . '/home.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerycolor', get_theme_part( THEME_JS . '/jquery.color.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    };
```

Which is currently in header.php, by putting it in a functions.php file instead. Trying to tidy everything up on a sprawling client's site. I'm using wp-framework and ideally would stick this inside the enqueue_assets function in the main parent_theme class. Although this isn't really a wp-framework issue, I'd just like to know:

How can I get is_home() to work from a functions file? Is there an alternative, using globals, I need to know about?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, if you want to target the *site Front Page*, you need to use `is_front_page()`. The `is_home()` conditional returns true when the *blog posts index* is displayed, which may or may not be on the *site Front Page*.

Second, you need to hook your function into an appropriate hook, which it appears in this case is `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

(Also: what is `get_theme_part()`? Is it a custom function in WP Framework?)

For example, you can do this in `functions.php`:

```
function mytheme_enqueue_front_page_scripts() {
    if( is_front_page() )
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'homestuff', get_theme_part( THEME_JS . '/home.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerycolor', get_theme_part( THEME_JS . '/jquery.color.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_front_page_scripts' );
```

Comment: Chip, you're a star. Thanks. (Yes, get_theme_part is a wp-framework thing. I swear by the new wp-framework release. It's awesome)

Comment: Oh, right on then. That function should, per best practice, be prefixed as `wpf_get_theme_part()` or something similar. But, I looked it up; very nice little function.